# How to disable click events checking of button at the starting of activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, http, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am creating one list view with text and buttons in that list view data was populated from async task and here i am displaying that list view with in dialog like this [image]. My problem is When the user selects the "spinner" value present in the list view and at the dialog popup time the async task i wrote inside `onItemclick` of the spinner was executing continuously displaying like this

[image].Please help me with this and sorry for asking question like this.This is my adapter code to execute clicking cancel button

```
leaves_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        //  leaves_type_string = leaves_type.getSelectedItem().toString();
            new update_leave_entry_breakup_values().execute("UpdateValues",
                    "1082", id_string, leaves_type.getSelectedItem().toString(), username, "",
                    "", "", "", "", "", "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

This is my async task:

```
  class update_leave_entry_breakup_values extends
            AsyncTask<String, integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressdialog_view.setMessage("Updating leaves...");
            progressdialog_view.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String TempMethod = params[0];
            String Flag = params[1];
            String value1 = params[2];
            String value2 = params[3];
            String value3 = params[4];
            String value4 = params[5];
            String value5 = params[6];
            String value6 = params[7];
            String value7 = params[8];
            String value8 = params[9];
            String value9 = params[10];
            String value10 = params[11];

            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, TempMethod);
                request.addProperty("Flag", Flag);
                request.addProperty("value1", value1);
                request.addProperty("value2", value2);
                request.addProperty("value3", value3);
                request.addProperty("value4", value4);
                request.addProperty("value5", value5);
                request.addProperty("value6", value6);
                request.addProperty("value7", value7);
                request.addProperty("value8", value8);
                request.addProperty("value9", value9);
                request.addProperty("value10", value10);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE Android_HttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                Android_HttpTransport.debug = true;
                Android_HttpTransport.call(NAME_SPACE + TempMethod, envelope);
                String responseXml = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                return responseXml;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressdialog_view.dismiss();

            if (result == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error while reading data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (result.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error while Updating data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Update Success",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `progressdialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

Comment: you have try to progressdialog.setCancelable(true); as like @IntelliJAmiya comment, then not get solution so you have to describe more about your quetion

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..Its not working dude and its not the problem with progress dialog i i think so..:( @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I edited my question@RaviVGHL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `notifyDataSetChanged();` from your click event,

---

```
final Button cancel = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancel.setTag(position);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int tag_position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                objects.remove(tag_position);
                notifyDataSetChanged(); // remove this
                new cancel_leave_entry_breakup_values().execute("UpdateValues", "1083",
                        leave_app.getID(), leave_app.getUsername().toString(),
                        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

            }
        });
```

According to me you are calling your adapter two times. you need to call it once.

Use `notifyDataSetChanged();` when you want to refresh data of listview like `OnRestart()` method.

Comment: But here i am writing in adapter how can we write restart method in side adapter @Amit Vaghela

Comment: no, it is an example to use notifyDataSetChanged(); I am saying that you are calling asynctask two time. call it once only by,   new cancel_leave_entry_breakup_values().execute("UpdateValues", "1083",
                        leave_app.getID(), leave_app.getUsername().toString(),
                        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

Comment: I am calling here only once can u tell me clearly @Amit Vaghela

Comment: remove notifyDataSetChanged(); from onclick and try @lakshman

Comment: Yes dude its working..thanks but i need to call that because i need to refresh that list when user clicks button @Amit Vaghela

Comment: okay. you can use notifyDataSetChanged(); in OnRestart() method to refresh listview @lakshman

Comment: Here i am updating values by click events from adapter but here i need write restart method inside adapter?

Comment: Solved by removing at the notify on data set changed but it was appearing continuously at the starting of the dialog popup but here i am not using notifyondatasetchanged chan@Amit Vaghela